# Adding multiple markers and launching into new activity on click -GOOGLE MAPS-Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How can I add multiple markers in my mapAcivity and launch into new acttivity by clicking on that marker. What I want to do is that when user searches for specific location in google map v2. He should be able to mark that location on click and launch into a new dialog activity, and then different actions will be called based on the co-ordinates of location. So far I have integrated the map but can't figure out how to add multiple markers. So far the code is

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
//import com.javaorigin.test.apk.R;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity 

{

private GoogleMap newmap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    Log.d("Map","MapCreated");
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #newmap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (newmap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        newmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (newmap != null) {
            setUpMap();
            Log.d("MAPS","Map working");


        }
        else Log.d("MAPS","not working");

    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #newmap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {

    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet"));

    // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    newmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   newmap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // set map type
    newmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    LatLng two = new LatLng(latitude+0.00005, longitude);
    LatLng three = new LatLng(latitude+0.00007, longitude);
    LatLng four = new LatLng(latitude+0.00009, longitude);


    // Show the current location in Google Map
    newmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    newmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My location"));
    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(two).title("two"));
    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(three).title("three"));
    newmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(four).title("four"));
    Log.d("LATITUDE",String.valueOf(latitude));
    Log.d("LONGITUDE",String.valueOf(longitude));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OnMarkerClickListener listener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            startActivity();
            return true;
        }

    };

    newmap.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);

    newmap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);


            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what startActivity() does?

Comment: starting activity, its just excample, in this line u should start your "dialog activity" or just dialog or whatever u want :) if this answer did help u, plz accept it.